# Java logger не устанавливается уровень логов

Tags: java

Добрый день. 
Создаю логгер:

```
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GameField.class.getName());
```

Ставлю ему:

```
log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

В документации написано:

```
setLevel(Level newLevel)
Set the log level specifying which message levels will be logged by this logger.
```

Но если создать два лога - один с уровнем конфиг, а другой с уровнем инфо:

```
    log.info("info log");
    log.config("config log");
```

в логи попадет только тот, который с уровнем инфо, что прямо противоречит тому что написано в документации. 
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию используется **ConsoleHandler** и у него установлен уровень `Level.INFO`.

Вы можете это исправить:

- создав и подключив (`-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<имя файла>`) свой файл **logging.properties**

  ```
  java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
  handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
  ```
- поменять системный файл **logging.properties**
- поменять уровень **ConsoleHandler**, который используется по умолчанию

  ```
  log.getParent().getHandlers()[0].setLevel(Level.ALL);
  ```
- добавить свой  **ConsoleHandler**

  ```
  // выключаем настройки по умолчанию иначе сообщения будут дублироваться
  LogManager.getLogManager().reset();

  ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
  handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
  handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
  log.addHandler(handler);
  log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
  ```